Can you tell if these two rational maps have relations or not?

Problem Setup

Here are two maps $\mathbb C^3\longrightarrow\mathbb C^3$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
           z \\
         \end{bmatrix}
\overset{f}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{x^2yz + 2xy^2z + y^3z + 2xyz^2 + 2y^2z^2 + yz^3 - x^3 - xy^2 - 2x^2z - xz^2 + 2x^2 - 2xy + 2xz - 3yz - x - 2z}{x^2yz + 2xy^2z + y^3z + 2xyz^2 + 2y^2z^2 + yz^3 - x^2y + y^3 + x^2z + y^2z + 2xz^2 + yz^2 + z^3 - x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 2xz + yz - z^2 + 2x - y + z - 1} \\
           \frac{-x^3z + xy^2z - 2x^2z^2 - xz^3 - x^2y - y^3 - 2y^2z - yz^2 - 2y^2 + xz - 4yz - y - 2z}{x^3z + 2x^2yz + xy^2z + 2x^2z^2 + 2xyz^2 + xz^3 - x^3 + xy^2 - x^2z - y^2z - xz^2 - 2yz^2 - z^3 + x^2 + 2xy - y^2 + xz - 2yz - z^2 + x - 2y - z - 1} \\
           \frac{x^3y - xy^3 + 2x^2yz + xyz^2 - 2x^2y - 2xy^2 - x^2z - 4xyz - y^2z - 2xz^2 - 2yz^2 - z^3 - xy - 2yz - z}{x^3y + 2x^2y^2 + xy^3 + 2x^2yz + 2xy^2z + xyz^2 + x^3 + x^2y - xy^2 - y^3 + 2x^2z - 2y^2z + xz^2 - yz^2 - x^2 - 3xy - y^2 - 2xz - 2yz - z^2 - x + y + 1} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
           z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{g}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{x^2yz + xy^2z + xyz^2 - x^2y - x^2z - xyz - xz^2 + z^2}{x^2yz + xy^2z + xyz^2 - xyz + xz^2 + yz^2 + z^3 - z^2} \\
           \frac{-x^2z^2 - xyz^2 - xz^3 - x^2y - x^2z + z^2}{x^3z + x^2yz + x^2z^2 - 2x^2z - xyz - xz^2 + xz} \\
           \frac{x^2yz + xy^2z + xyz^2 - x^2y - x^2z - xyz - xz^2 + z^2}{x^3y + x^2y^2 + x^2yz - x^2y + x^2z + xyz + xz^2 - xz}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Surprisingly, these functions are involutions (i.e. their own inverses). Which, in particular, means they are birational automorphisms (or "symmetries") of $\mathbb C^3$.
These functions are also interesting because they map any solution of
$$x+ y + z=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$
to anther solution. In that sense, they are non-trivial birational symmetries of this equation. We can call them symmetries of "inversive tri-sums". In effect, we can use these maps to calculate "not-obvious" tri-sums from "obvious" ones. For example,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
           1/2 \\
           1 \\
           2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{g}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
           19/68 \\
           76/51 \\
           17/6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
More technically speaking, $f$ and $g$ both stabilize the the quartic surface
$$X=V(E_1\cdot E_3-E_2)$$
where the polynomials
$$E_1=x+y+z$$
$$E_2=yz+zx+xy$$
$$E_3=xyz$$
are the elementary symmetric polynomials in three variables.

The Question

Can you tell $f$ and $g$ have any relations? Or instead, do they generate a copy of $\mathbb Z_2*\mathbb Z_2$ in the Cremona group of rank three? I.e. in Bir$(\mathbb C^3)$. Or even, is it possible that $f$ and $g$ have some relation, but only when restricted to $X$? That is, could some function like $f\circ g\circ f\circ g\circ f\circ g\circ f$ possibly be the identity on $X$ but not the identity on all of $\mathbb C^3$?
On the computational side, I've calculated
$$f\circ g,\quad g\circ f,\quad f\circ g\circ f,\quad \text{and}\quad g\circ f \circ g$$
and none of them is identity. For instance, the numerator of the $x$-component of $g\circ f\circ g$ has hundreds of monomials and begins with $$-4x^{11}y^5z^5- 28x^{10}y^6z^5 - 84x^9y^7z^5 - \ ...$$
Here is the code used:
R.<x, y, z> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
S = R.fraction_field()
x, y, z = S.gens()

class Bir:
    def __init__(self, f_x, f_y, f_z):
        self.v = vector([f_x, f_y, f_z])
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Bir(*self.v(*other.v(x, y, z)))
    
    def display(self):
        print('x ->', self.v[0])
        print('y ->', self.v[1])
        print('z ->', self.v[2])
        
    def latex_paste(self):
        print(str(self.v).replace('*', '').replace(')', '}').replace('(', '{').replace('/', ''))


# Raycasting from [x-1, y+z] and [z, x].
f = Bir(
    (x^2*y*z + x*y^2*z + x*y*z^2 - x^2*y - x^2*z - x*y*z - x*z^2 + z^2) / (x^2*y*z + x*y^2*z + x*y*z^2 - x*y*z + x*z^2 + y*z^2 + z^3 - z^2),
    (-x^2*z^2 - x*y*z^2 - x*z^3 - x^2*y - x^2*z + z^2) / (x^3*z + x^2*y*z + x^2*z^2 - 2*x^2*z - x*y*z - x*z^2 + x*z),
    (x^2*y*z + x*y^2*z + x*y*z^2 - x^2*y - x^2*z - x*y*z - x*z^2 + z^2) / (x^3*y + x^2*y^2 + x^2*y*z - x^2*y + x^2*z + x*y*z + x*z^2 - x*z),
)

# Raycasting from [x-1, y+z] and [y+1, z+x].
g = Bir(
    (x^2*y*z + 2*x*y^2*z + y^3*z + 2*x*y*z^2 + 2*y^2*z^2 + y*z^3 - x^3 - x*y^2 - 2*x^2*z - x*z^2 + 2*x^2 - 2*x*y + 2*x*z - 3*y*z - x - 2*z) / (x^2*y*z + 2*x*y^2*z + y^3*z + 2*x*y*z^2 + 2*y^2*z^2 + y*z^3 - x^2*y + y^3 + x^2*z + y^2*z + 2*x*z^2 + y*z^2 + z^3 - x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2 - 2*x*z + y*z - z^2 + 2*x - y + z - 1),
    (-x^3*z + x*y^2*z - 2*x^2*z^2 - x*z^3 - x^2*y - y^3 - 2*y^2*z - y*z^2 - 2*y^2 + x*z - 4*y*z - y - 2*z) / (x^3*z + 2*x^2*y*z + x*y^2*z + 2*x^2*z^2 + 2*x*y*z^2 + x*z^3 - x^3 + x*y^2 - x^2*z - y^2*z - x*z^2 - 2*y*z^2 - z^3 + x^2 + 2*x*y - y^2 + x*z - 2*y*z - z^2 + x - 2*y - z - 1),
    (x^3*y - x*y^3 + 2*x^2*y*z + x*y*z^2 - 2*x^2*y - 2*x*y^2 - x^2*z - 4*x*y*z - y^2*z - 2*x*z^2 - 2*y*z^2 - z^3 - x*y - 2*y*z - z) / (x^3*y + 2*x^2*y^2 + x*y^3 + 2*x^2*y*z + 2*x*y^2*z + x*y*z^2 + x^3 + x^2*y - x*y^2 - y^3 + 2*x^2*z - 2*y^2*z + x*z^2 - y*z^2 - x^2 - 3*x*y - y^2 - 2*x*z - 2*y*z - z^2 - x + y + 1),
)

print('f:')
f.display()
print(' ')

print('g:')
g.display()
print(' ')

print('f*f:')
(f*f).display()
print(' ')

print('g*g:')
(g*g).display()
print(' ')

print('f*g:')
(f*g).display()
print(' ')


Ambitious Followup Questions

So in addition to $f$ and $g$, there are some "obvious" symmetries of $\mathbb Q(X)$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{\nu}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
       -x \\
       -y \\
       -z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{\sigma\in S^3}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
       \sigma(x) \\
       \sigma(y) \\
       \sigma(z) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{\tau_x}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
       -1/x \\
       y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{\tau_y}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       -1/y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y \\
       z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{\tau_z}{\longmapsto}
\begin{bmatrix}
       x \\
       y \\
       -1/z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
These generate a group of order $96$.
$$G=\langle \nu\rangle \times (S_3\ltimes \langle \tau_x, \tau_y, \tau_z\rangle)\quad\cong\quad\mathbb Z_2 \times (S_3\ltimes \mathbb Z_2^3)$$
And it's natural to ask: Do $f$ and $g$ have any relations with the "obvious" symmetries $G$. Could some function like $\tau_x\circ \sigma\circ g\circ \nu\circ f\circ \nu$ possibly be the identity.
Supposing one answers these questions, it's again natural to ask: Have we found all birational symmetries of $X$? For example, in the case that $f$ and $g$ have no relations either with each other or with $G$, can we conclude that
$$\textbf{Bir}(X)=G*\langle f\rangle*\langle g\rangle \cong \Big(\mathbb Z_2 \times (S_3\ltimes \mathbb Z_2^3)\Big)*\mathbb Z_2*\mathbb Z_2$$
Lastly and most ambitiously, supposing we verify the previous isomorphism or something like it, it's natural to ask: Can we generate all rational points of $X$ by applying the former group iteratively to some finite set of initial rational points? (or finite set of families of rational points?) I.e. is there some finite (or deterministically enumerable) set of points $P=\{ p_\alpha\}_\alpha $ so that
$$\mathbb Q(X)=\bigcup_{\alpha} G (p_\alpha)$$
We would hope that the set of "obvious" rational points on $X$ would work. This would consist of the rational points on six "skew" lines
$$(1,\lambda, -\lambda),\quad (\lambda, 1, -\lambda),\quad (\lambda, -\lambda, 1),\quad (-1,\lambda, -\lambda),\quad (\lambda, -1, -\lambda),\quad (\lambda, -\lambda, -1)$$
the rational points on the axes,
$$(\lambda, 0, 0),\quad (0,\lambda, 0),\quad (0, 0, \lambda)$$
and the rational points on six hyperbola,
$$(1,\lambda, 1/\lambda),\quad (\lambda, 1, 1/\lambda),\quad (\lambda, 1/\lambda, 1),\quad (-1,\lambda, 1/\lambda),\quad (\lambda, -1, 1/\lambda),\quad (\lambda, 1/\lambda, -1)$$
where we imagine $\lambda$ ranging over $\mathbb C$.
Here's some images of $\mathbb R(X)$ in SageMath with the former "obvious" points marked out as green skew-lines, red axes, and yellow hyperbola.
$\mathbb R(X)$" /> 
At this point, we are effectively asking for something like a Mordell-Weil theorem for the quartic surface $X$. Is the group of rational symmetries of $X$ finitely generated? Is the set of all rational points the union of finitely many (families of) orbits under the group's action? And so on. This feels like a lot to ask. But I'd really like to learn more about inversive tri-sums, and this approach felt like the natural (although difficult) appproach to enumerating them systematically.
